# Are Memory Address Hardcoded on RAM Chip?

Tags: microprocessors

I was Learning 16-bit 8086 Microprocessor and i got to know it can access address upto 1MB(00000-FFFFF) but my question is Are these address i.e 00000,0001D,etc are hardcoded on the RAM or how these addresses are defined i mean DOES RAM have built in hardcoded address ?

Comment: This is really a computer engineering question.  Typically, the CPU will have address pins, which are wired to the RAM's address pins.  These may be multiplexed with data pins.  Some address pins may be wired to chip select pins on the RAM.

Comment: In short you are telling about address bus,Microprocessor puts address on address bus and communicates but are ADDRESSES HARDCODED on RAM??

Comment: 8086 and RAM are interfaced over a MMU (Memory Management Unit). It handles the translation of address to actual RAM location.

Comment: Means You are Saying Addresses are not hardcoded,MMU tries to find out the empty location and gives address to RAM and stores data at that location ? Is that ?